# Convert ADPropertyValueCollection to System.Collections.Hashtable

Tags: powershell

When I read "Certificates" property of an AD user like this:

```
$allProfileRawCerts = (Get-ADUser -Server example.com -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail} -Property Certificates).Certificates
```

The resulting datatype is ADPropertyValueCollection.

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                                         
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                                         
True     False    ADPropertyValueCollection                System.Collections.CollectionBase
```

However, if I want to use this to set the property, apparently different datatype is expected:

```
Get-ADUser -Server example.com -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail} | Set-ADUser -Certificates $array
Set-ADUser : Cannot convert 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection' to the type 'System.Collections.Hashtable' required by parameter 'Certificates'. Specified method is not 
supported.
At line:1 char:100
+ ... 68 -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail} | Set-ADUser -Certificates $allProfileRawCerts
+                                                                    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

How to convert it so I can use it?

Comment: Where and how do you populate `$array`?

Comment: It's same as $allProfileRawCerts, I updated the question. The effect of trying too many things and then c&p without checking, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out RTFM would be a good advice.

-Certificate doesn't just accept certificate list, it accepts hash table of "operation"="certificate", example:

```
-Certificates @{Add=value1,value2,...};@{Remove=value3,value4,...}
```

So the answer is (I think, still testing):

```
Get-ADUser -Server example.com -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail} | Set-ADUser -Certificates @{Add=$allpProfileCerts}
```